# How to add a background image attached to a text in a title with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Do you have any idea how to do this with HTML and CSS? Adding an image around a text in a title. See screenshot.

Title with blue background image around a single word:

[image]

Comment: use background-position prop to achieve it...please paste the code to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this you want to achive ?**

The CSS background properties are used to define the background effects 
    for elements.

CSS background properties:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

```html
<p style="margin-right:150px;">Some text with a <span style=";border:1px solid gray;padding:8px;background:#e1efbb url('http://via.placeholder.com/50x50')">background image </span></p>
```

Good luck